# How to retrieve the value for the Key in the Web.Config via C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-config

I am building a Webservice via VS2012 and need to fetch some data from the Web.Config file based on the dynamic data I would get from an Stored Procedure.

Code block in Web.Config

```
  <domainSource>
     <domainIDs>
         <add name="0" source="170" />
         <add name="1" source="171" />
         <add name="2" source="172" />
         <add name="3" source="173" />
         <add name="12" source="174" />
     </domainIDs>
  </domainSource>
```

Source code in DomainConfiguration.cs as below

```
public class DomainElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)this["name"]; }
            set { this["name"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("source", IsRequired = true, DefaultValue = "170")]
        public string Source
        {
            get { return (string)this["source"]; }
            set { this["source"] = value; }
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(DomainElement))]
    public class DomainCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new DomainElement();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((DomainElement)element).Name;
        }
    }

    public class DomainSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("domainIDs", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
        public DomainCollection DomainID
        {
            get { return (DomainCollection)this["domainIDs"]; }
            set { this["domainIDs"] = value; }
        }
    }
```

Sourcecode in the main cs file from where I wish to retrieve the data from the Web.Config

```
vDomainID = new B2B().Domain(SourceID, Subject);

DomainCollection collection;

collection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("domainSource") as DomainCollection;
vDomainSource = collection[vDomainID];
```

This is where I am stuck **vDomainID** would be a value 0/1/2/3/12, based on this value I need to fetch its respective Source from the ***Web.Config***. Any help on this aspect would be really appreciated.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: @Bryan .Net Framework 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close; you want to cast `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("domainSource")` to `DomainSection` ***(Not DomainCollection)***.

```
public class DomainElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)this["name"]; }
        set { this["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("source", IsRequired = true, DefaultValue = "170")]
    public string Source
    {
        get { return (string)this["source"]; }
        set { this["source"] = value; }
    }
}

[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(DomainElement))]
public class DomainCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new DomainElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((DomainElement)element).Name;
    }
}

public class DomainSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("domainIDs", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    public virtual DomainCollection domainIDs
    {
        get { return (DomainCollection)this["domainIDs"]; }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
string vDomainID = "0";
var domainSource = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("domainSource") as DomainSection;
var domainIDs = domainSource.domainIDs;
foreach (DomainElement item in domainIDs)
{
    if (item.Name.Equals(vDomainID))
    {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Comment: the above code worked, thanks a ton. But there was a suggestion from my peers to use the `code`<section name="domainsource" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler"/>`code`.
So tried this way to get the required value for the key that I pass, but I seem to miss something and it errors out.                `code`NameValueCollection domainSource = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("domainsource");
                vDomainSource = domainSource[vDomainID];`code`

Could you please lend a hand on this?

Comment: It is totally different from original question. Could you please create a new question with those code?

Comment: have created a new question "How to retrieve the value for the Key in the Web.Config using DictionarySectionHandler", can you please review and advise ?